# Ractive binding to parent

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I have a simple template for posts with comments:

```
{{#each Posts}}
  {{Text}}
  {{#each Comments}}
    //how can I bind to Post.Id here? Like {{../Id}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

How can I bind to a parent #each block (I need to get post's Id property) inside comments #each block?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ractive supports [Restricted References](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/references#restricted-references), so just like you have it:

```
{{#each Posts}}
  {{Text}}
  {{#each Comments}}
    Post Id: {{../../Id}}
    Comment Id: {{Id}}
  {{/each}}
{{/each}}
```

You can also alias Parent fields if you don't need bidirectional updates on the aliased field:

```
{{#each Posts}}
  {{Text}}
  {{#with { PostId: Id } }}
  {{#each Comments}}
    Post Id: {{PostId}}
    Comment Id: {{Id}}
  {{/each}}
  {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Tried the {{../Id}} syntax out but it doesn't seem to work: http://jsfiddle.net/pj6myzch/3/

Comment: Sorry, needs to go up two paths, one to `Comments`, the n to `Posts`. See http://jsfiddle.net/pj6myzch/4/. Fixed example.